# Is there a way to integrate generic custom identity provider like NHS Login with Azure ADB2C which provide private key to fetch access token

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

We are trying to integrate custom identity provider like NHS Login with Azure ADB2C which provides private key to fetch access token. When we try to login using credentials, we get the error saying "We encountered an error connecting to the identity provider. Please try again later." Is there any source or starting point which we can refer where user has integrated generic custom identity provider like NHS Login with Azure ADB2C successfully and able to fetch access token using private key as token endpoint auth method [Azure ADB2C tech profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/openid-connect-technical-profile)

Answer (score 1):

(new account so can't comment on the above - but i think the below is useful to this thread).

Jas Suri, Could you possibly expand on the last sentence please, as from what I've experienced, its a requirement?

> It is best to use the OAuth2 technical profile to get the most out of
> NHS Login platform

I have now got NHS Login working with Azure B2C, but I had initially had the claims tech profile setup as OpenIdConnect, but was getting validation errors:

> (IDX10618:
> AsymmetricSecurityKey.GetHashAlgorithmForSignature( 'RS512' ) threw an
> exception.\nAsymmetricSecurityKey:
> 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.RsaSecurityKey'\nSignatureAlgorithm:
> 'RS512', check to make sure the SignatureAlgorithm is supported)

Answer (score 0):

We have integrated NHS Login with AAD B2C.

The document linked shows two metadata items that make us compatible with NHS Login:

`token_endpoint_auth_method`:   Specifies how Azure AD B2C sends the authentication header to the token endpoint. Possible values: client_secret_post (default), and client_secret_basic (public preview), private_key_jwt (public preview).

`token_signing_algorithm`: Specifies the signing algorithm to use when token_endpoint_auth_method is set to private_key_jwt. Possible values: RS256 (default) or RS512.

The technical profile will look like this:

```xml
        <TechnicalProfile Id="NHS-Login-OAUTH2">
          <DisplayName>NHS-Login-OAUTH2</DisplayName>
          <Description>Login with your NHS account</Description>
          <Protocol Name="OAuth2" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="authorization_endpoint">https://auth.sandpit.signin.nhs.uk/authorize</Item>
            <Item Key="AccessTokenEndpoint">https://auth.sandpit.signin.nhs.uk/token</Item>
            <Item Key="ClaimsEndpoint">https://auth.sandpit.signin.nhs.uk/userinfo</Item>
            <Item Key="client_id">yourClientIdFromNHS</Item>
            <Item Key="scope">openid email profile phone profile_extended gp_integration_credentials</Item>
            <Item Key="response_mode">form_post</Item>
            <Item Key="BearerTokenTransmissionMethod">AuthorizationHeader</Item>
            <Item Key="response_types">code</Item>
            <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
            <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">false</Item>
            <Item Key="token_endpoint_auth_method">private_key_jwt</Item>
            <Item Key="token_signing_algorithm">RS512</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="assertion_signing_key" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_NhsSandpit" />
          </CryptographicKeys>
..snip..
```

NHS Login requires `private_key_jwt` and `RS512`. This will use a client assertion to authenticate to the NHS Login `/token` endpoint.

Take the PEM file which NHS login docs state to generate, and convert it to PFX. Upload that PFX into B2C policy keys. This is referenced in the `CryptographicKeys` node of the technical profile.

It is best to use the OAuth2 technical profile to get the most out of NHS Login platform.

Comment: Can you please share the snippet code for OutputClaims and OutputClaimsTransformations. We are still having error during claim exchange

Comment: Even-though we have specified token signing algorithm as RS512 in custom profile, NHS support mentioned error as "Error parsing JWT: The parsed JWT indicates it was signed with the HS256 signature algorithm" during /token endpoint

Comment: The rest of the technical profile wouldn’t cause your observation. It’s more likely your certificate is the issue. Can you find the policy key in the Azure Portal and share the JSON properties.

Comment: Also make sure the Key Id is `assertion_signing_key` under `CryptographicKeys` node.

Comment: Followed this https://nhsconnect.github.io/nhslogin/generating-pem/ to generate private key which we have added as manual type to policy keys as we got validation message when tried to upload .pem extension file.

Comment: I converted the PEM into a PFX when I last did this. Can you give more detail on how you uploaded the PEM to AAD B2C policy keys?

Comment: I have extracted the content of private_key.pem file using notepad and added as secret to the manual option with key usage as signature.

Comment: That’s the issue, a Secret is a symmetric key, creating a HS256 operation. You need to convert it to a PFX to create an RSA sig.

Comment: I have converted PEM file to PFX and it worked !! Thank you so much..

Comment: Updated my post to reflect solution.